# How to have full rotation of a circular object using uiview animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiviewanimation

I am trying to loop over partial circles to achieve the animation but it only turns 180 degrees, and then starts again from 0 degrees to 180 degrees. So there is an abrupt jump from 180 degrees to 360 degrees. How can I have my circular image object rotate continuously without any jumps? Here is my current code:

```
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:ROTATE_ANIMATION_DURATION/2 delay:0 options:options 
       animations:^{
           view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);}//1st step of animation finished
       completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [UIView animateWithDuration:ROTATE_ANIMATION_DURATION/2 delay:0 options:options 
                animations:^{
                    view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);} //2nd step of animation finished
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {nil;
                }];
```

Comment: Using CA Animation to do this now, would still like to see if someone has a solution with UIView animation block.

Answer (score 14):

Spin UI Object, animation rotate 360 Degree
you’ll need to add the QuartzCore Framework to your project and include the

```
#import QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h
```

Add animation for object:

```
 CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 6;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = 1e100f;
    [myview.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

Comment: it really seems to be the very best way to do it in 2013 - even now that blocks are here!

Answer (score 3):

I found some old code that I use to rotate a view 360 degrees, I hope it helps. You'll need to import QuartzCore.

```
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.zRad"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0];

rotationAnimation.duration = 3;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = 
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];

[viewToAnimate.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation.zRad"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using CA Animation now. It's weird that we cannot accomplish this simple animation using UIView Animation.

Comment: Yeah, I also gave it a try with the UIView animation block but without success.

Answer (score 1):

There are following different ways to perform 360 degree animation with UIView.

Using **CABasicAnimation**

```
var rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
rotationAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: (Double.pi * 2.0))
rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0
rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 100.0
view.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

Here is an extension functions for UIView that handles start & stop rotation operations:

```
extension UIView {

    // Start rotation
    func startRotation() {
        let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotation.fromValue = 0
        rotation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi * 2)
        rotation.duration = 1.0
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
        self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }

    // Stop rotation
    func stopRotation() {
        self.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

Now using, **UIView.animation** closure:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
      view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi)) 
}) { (isAnimationComplete) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
      view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BOOL animating;

- (void)spinWithOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options {  
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                             delay:0
                           options:options
                        animations:^{

                           self.imageToMove.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageToMove.transform, M_PI / 2);
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                           if (finished) {
                              if (animating) {
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
                              } else if (options != UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) {
                                 [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut];
                              }
                           }
                        }];
}
- (void)startSpin {   
     if (!animating) {
        animating = YES;
        [self spinWithOptions: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn];    
     } 
}

- (void)stopSpin  {
    // set the flag to stop spinning after one last 90 degree increment
    animating = NO; 
}
```

You can start and stop the view animation by calling startSpin and stopSpin methods respectively.

And here is the swift relevant answer:

```
func spin(with options: UIViewAnimationOptions) {
             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: options,
        animations: {() -> Void in

                    self.imageToRotate.transform = self.imageToRotate.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)  
                }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in

            if finished {
               if self.animating {
                  self.spin(with: .curveLinear)
               }
               else if options != .curveEaseOut {
                  self.spin(with: .curveEaseOut)
               }
            }
        })
}

func startSpin() {
   if !animating {
      animating = true
      spin(with: .curveEaseIn)
   }
}

func stopSpin() {
    animating = false
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate why this code does what it does, now it is just a wall of code